# How do I Color The background of multiple cells in one line of code?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, background-color

I have a gridview that I color specific cells backgrounds.

I have a row that has 16 columns and I want to color the first 14 cells.

Can I do this with one line of code for all 14 cells?

I currently color each cell like this:

```
row.Cells(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGray
row.cells(1).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGray
row.cells(2).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGray
etc......
```

I want to be able to have one line of code that colors cells 0 through 14 all at one time. Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET means Web and HTML. Use the same CSS class for all cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want one line?

```
For i = 0 to 13 : row.Cells(i).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGray : Next
```

Comment: It's ASP.NET. The correct answer would be to use CSS